msodbc17 installation error [IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed on cloud deployment
Im working on cloud native solution, in which I'm having a project pod in which project using mssql database. Also, im executing an installation pod for mssql which uses ubuntu image and install the necessary msodbc17 driver. after the installation im copying the lib files to project pod. and ENV ODBCINI and ENV ODBCSYSINI is set still im unable to access the database when i execute the project.
I used this command for installation of msodbc17 driver:
args:
- |
set -e
apt-get update
apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https gnupg2
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list >        etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev
apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
echo "ODBC driver installation completed."
cp -r /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/* /home/shared-resources/msodbc/lib/
Also i copied this .so files to lib dir:
libltdl.so.7  libltdl.so.7.3.1  libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.6.1  libmsodbcsql-17.so  libodbc.so  libodbc.so.2  libodbc.so.2.0.0  libodbcinst.so  libodbcinst.so.2  libodbcinst.so.2.0.0  msodbcsqlr17.rll
I tried every way to resolve the issue but it is not working. Please somebody guide me on this.

What Docker image are you starting with? Or, if you don't know that, what's the output of cat /etc/os-release when run from a shell on the container?

Aside... apt-key add has been deprecated since Debian 9 days. You might wish to read through Microsoft's documentation, Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux), to see how it's done these days.

Which Docker base image are you starting with? If you docker run -it --rm ubuntu:latest grep PRETTY_NAME /etc/os-release, for example, you'll see that it's PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS". You're referencing https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list which is intended for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa and contains packages that aren't compatible with Ubuntu 24.04.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. But the problem is not that, when i install the odbc driver directly to the project pod it works fine. But same way when i execute a mssql pod to install the msodbc17 and copy the lib files to a shared folder which is accessible to the project pod then its not working.

That's not really the same process, though, is it? I would suggest building your image locally, using docker save YourImageId > msodbc17.tar and then inspecting the contents of the new layers in msodbc17.tar because even when minimally doing ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev that one command causes 59MB of layer changes. Among other things it could be upset that its language resources in /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/share/resources/en_US/msodbcsqlr17.rll are missing.

Yes, i did that. I gone through the layers like all the installation files are located at /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/ If i'm not wrong copying the lib files to project pod should work right? means msodbc should be connected inside the project pod. But it's not working. could you please let me know If I'm getting anything wrong?

@AlwaysLearning You're right! the error was caused due to the lib file was unable to load the msodbcsqlr17.rll file on loc /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/share/resources/en_US/msodbcsqlr17.rll. But the thing i did is i manually copied this file to shared-resources from mssql pod and then from project pod i manually created the dir and move the file to that location. But is there any way means can we load this rll file from any location. Is there any custom path can we provide to the lib file which will load the rll file from that location?
